# What is the best way to unconvert sanitized data?

Tags: xml, database, sanitization

I have a very large set of data (one of stackoverflow's data dumps) which is completely in raw and sanitized form.

```
For example:  &lt;/p&gt;
```

Is there an already established way to convert the above and similar back to their original form for readability and usability?  A python script or function call by chance?

Comment: this is way too generic. numerous languages have such features. In addition, if you use a proper XML parser, those escapes won't show up in your strings in the first place

Comment: I was asking for a way to unconvert the sanitization - I don't care how.   PS its 30Gb

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I had to use to get everything working correctly - note that the HTML parser didn't do everything I wanted with my data-set

## !/usr/bin/python3

```
    import html.parser
    import string
    import sys
    
    # Amount of lines to put into a buffer before writing
    BUFFER_SIZE_LINES = 1024
    html_parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
    
    # Few HTML reserved chars that are not being cleaned up by HTMLParser
    dict = {}
    dict[ '&quot;' ] = '"'
    dict[ '&apos;' ] = "'"
    dict[ '&amp;' ] = '&'
    dict[ '&lt;' ] = '<'
    dict[ '&gt;' ] = '>'
    
    # Process the file
    def ProcessLargeTextFile(fileIn, fileOut):
        r = open(fileIn, "r")
        w = open(fileOut, "w")
        buff = ""
        buffLines = 0
        for lineIn in r:
    
            lineOut = html_parser.unescape(lineIn)
            for key, value in dict.items():
                lineOut = lineOut.replace(key,value)
    
            buffLines += 1
            
            if buffLines >= BUFFER_SIZE_LINES:
                w.write(buff)
                buffLines = 1
                buff = ""
    
            buff += lineOut + "\n"
    
        w.write(buff)
        r.close()
        w.close()
    
    
    # Now run
    ProcessLargeTextFile(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```